# Keycloak version compatibility issue with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am integrating keycloak 6.0.1 with springboot version 1.5.4, but I am getting application deployment error as below -

```
2019-07-01 16:36:19.613  INFO 4920 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'securityProperties' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=securityProperties; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=securityProperties; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class]]
2019-07-01 16:36:19.789 ERROR 4920 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/undertow/UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone help me out how to resolve this issue ?

I tried downloading keycloak 3.3.0.final version as suggested by some blog to use with mentioned springboot version, but I could get download link for keycloak 3.3.0 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` to integrate with keycloak then you need to use Keycloak `4.0.0.Final` which supports spring-boot `1.5.2.RELEASE`

You can check the dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter/4.0.0.Final)

With keycloak  `6.0.1` supports spring-boot `2.0.3.RELEASE`

Comment: From where I can download keycloak 4.0.0.Final or lower version. Keycloak website has only 4.8.3 or latest version available to download. I tried to download 3.3.0 but could not found. Not sure why keycloak removed older version.

Comment: Looks older versions are no more available try this https://downloads.jboss.org/keycloak/4.0.0.Final/keycloak-4.0.0.Final.zip

Comment: Got from above link, thanks!  ```Just for understanding if any workaround possible if we wanted to use keycloak latest version in future with springboot 1.5, there should be as keycloak removed older version from it's archive```

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around Keycloak last 2 weeks.

I made Keycloak 6.0.1 working with Spring Boot 1.4.1. Just tried your Spring Boot version 1.5.2, looks working.

I did my example based on that repo
https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-admin-keycloak-example

Removed spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency as don't care about it.

todo-service pom.xml I got is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>todo-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>todo-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.10</lombok.version>
    <keycloak.version>6.0.1</keycloak.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Play around that repo, update application properties to your keycloak settings, make it working, and do copy necessary dependencies to your original project until you get what you need (what I did for my)

Conclusion: Keycloak 6.0.1 can work with Spring Boot 1.x